# How to create a virtual display?

Tags: c#, screen

The question is simple, but I guess the answer might not be.

I want to create a display device, on which the GPU would render a desktop or a video game. However, this device would not be connected to any physical screen on the video card port. The data rendered would be retrieved and streamed somewhere else over network.

A bit similar to what OnLive did, but I would like to stream that video output over LAN. Obviously it must be a full and real display so that existing applications or video games could work properly on it.

Is it even possible in C#?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in C# as the .Net framework doesn't run at a deep enough trust level to allow it to make a virtual display adapter. Also, as much as I love C#, I don't think it'd be fast enough for this kind of thing. This is screaming C++ and a virtual device driver. Why ? You can't write windows device drivers in normal C#.

Comment: To clarify, for the pedantic, you *can* write a device driver in C#, what you can't do is write one that Windows will use!

Comment: What's the point of a device driver that Windows can't use? :D

Comment: Good question: Windows is not the only Platform for .Net code; You've got Linux and Mac (with Silverlight/Moonlight/Mono) and MS even had a research OS called Singularity which was written in managed code:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(operating_system)

Comment: Mac or Linux would allowed managed code such level of trust? Beside that... You're saying in C++, tricking the OS into thinking there's an extra monitor and sending the rendering stream from the GPU back to the CPU would be something possible?

Comment: Not saying they'd allow it out of the box; but you could hack it to do so; This is not a solution though, I simply mentioned that for sake of completeness. But you could definitely write a driver in C++ that looks like a monitor, to the GPU but sends the bits to the network instead of a display adaptor. How? I don't know, that's a lot more complex then we usually deal with here, but I would say that if VNC/RemoteDesktop can do it, then you can too.

Comment: @LightStriker did you ever find out how to do this?

Answer (score -4):

surely you could link it up as an output stream with your processed frames, piped to a network socket or such?

Comment: The networking is not the problem... My problem is actually creating the device so that a GPU would draw on it. I'm looking that route because there is no guaranty that the resolution I want it drawn to is the same as the screen connected to the computer. Where do I get that output stream??